# Google NDB: Adding an entity with non existing parent

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a web application based on Google App Engine (Python / Webapp2) and Google NDB Datastore. 
I assumed that if I tried to add a new entity using as parent key the key of a no longer existing entity an exception was thrown. I have instead found the entity is actually created.
Am i doing something wrong?

I may check before whether the parent still exist through a keys_only query. Does it consume GAE read quotas?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a key for any entity whether this entity exists or not. This is because a key is simply an encoding of an entity kind and either an id or name (and ancestor keys, if any).

This means that you can store a child entity before a parent entity is saved, as long as you know the parent's id or name. You cannot reassign a child from one parent to another, though.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, the [AppEngine pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) says:

*Calls to the datastore API result in the following billable operations. Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or keys-only queries. These operations are free.*

Complementing on @andrei's answer to the first question, *no key reference* in Ndb is checked for refering to an existing entity, this is true for keys used as parent, as well as for keys used as ̀`KeyProperty` within an entity.